# Javascript assiging multiple values to `ternary` operator

Tags: javascript

How to assign multiple values to `ternary` operator? is that not possible? I tried like this, but getting error:

```
size === 3 ? (  var val1=999,  var val2=100; )  : 0;
```

and

```
size === 3 ? (  var val1=999; var val2=100; )  : 0;
```

above both approach throws error. how to set both `var val1` and `var val2`;

I can directly declare it. But I would like to know the ternary operator approach here.

Comment: Why not use `if`? Also ` var val1=999,  var val2=100;` is illegal syntax

Comment: Possible duplicate of [declaring a variable within conditional expressions (ternary operator)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19071803/declaring-a-variable-within-conditional-expressions-ternary-operator)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```js
var size=3;
var val1=null;
var val2=null;
size === 3 ? (  val1=999,val2=100 )  : 0;
console.log(val1,val2)
```

Comment: Please add explanation as to what have you changes and what does your answer adds to this page that no one else has not address. You are answering for readers

Answer (score 1):

Its a syntax error .You could use like this separate call

```js
var size=3;
var  val1 = size === 3 ? 999  : 0;
var  val2 = size === 3 ? 100  : 0;
console.log(val1,val2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```js
var val1 = 0,
  val2 = 0,
  size = 3;
3 === size ? function() {
  val1 = 999;
  val2 = 100
}() : 0;
console.log(val1, val2);
```

Comment: You do not need IIFE here

Comment: Though it does work correctly (I didn't think it would).  It's much better habit than `eval`, it's more verbose than `(val1 = 999, val2 = 100)`, and it's more insane than just using an `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of ternary operator is

```
condition ? expr1 : expr2
```

`var val1=999; var val2=100;` is a valid **declaration** (`var val1=999,  var val2=100;` is not), but **NOT** an **expression**. So you can't use them the way you've done it in your code. However, you can make it into an expression by using the [eval function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) like so:

```
size === 3 ? eval('var val1=999; var val2=100;')  : 0;
```

Of course, as the others have pointed out. Using `eval` is the wrong approach to take. I am showing you how it could be done for the sake of answering your question.

Comment: Please don't use or recommend using eval unless it's absolutely necessary.  In this case it is definitely not necessary.

Comment: I assumed you were referring to assigning inside the ternary expressions as at the point of commenting no one had pointed out eval is the wrong approach to take.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `if` statement.

```
var val1;
var val2;
if (size === 3) {
     val1 = 999;
     val2 = 100;
}
```

Whilst D-reaper's answer answers your question, really your question is not the right thing to ask.  (Additionally `eval` is useful very very occasionally but is otherwise considered "evil" as it prevents various JavaScript engine optimisations and opens security holes like XSS if used on stored user input data).

Ternary operators are useful when you're using them to **assign to** another variable like:

```
var val1 = size === 3 ? 999 : 0;
```

In your example the fact you do no assignment, the first expression does not intend to return a value and the second value of `0` is ignored and therefore redundant is a very strong *code smell* they should alert you to there being a better easier way of doing what you want.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my try: it works fine for me:

```
createDigit : function( size ) {
                var val1, val2;
                size === 3 ? (  val1=999,  val2=100  )  :  size === 2 ? (  val1=99,  val2=10 )  : 0;
                //generates only 3 digit values
                return Math.floor( Math.random()*(val1-val2+1 )) + val2;
            },
```

Comment: Dear friend, you should **only** answer your own question when there is something that you have researched and found something that will help others. Also in my understanding, this **is not** what ternary operator is for

Comment: @Rajesh that's usually true but in this case it was very helpful as he's answered a different question than the one he was asking.

Comment: @AJP Ternary operations are suited for single values. Adding expression in them allows you to do more stuff but its not ideal. An `if..else if.. else` ladder would suit more in this situation. Also, dupe shared by Andreas explains why it fails. So I still would stick to my comment

Comment: I completely agree with your technical appraisal I hope you also agree that his answer is very useful to determine what question he was actually asking.  I have voted to close his question as it's not clear it's actually what he was asking.

Comment: @user2024080 note that Sikorski's answer stackoverflow.com/a/43931678/539490 works for any positive value of `size` as opposed to only 3 and 2.

Answer (score -1):

I see what you are trying to do, you can use `Math.pow()` to generate numbers instead of checking on `size` manually. I have put down two methods below : `createDigit` is mine which can generate numbers for any size given using `Math.pow()` and `createDigitBuggy` is yours which will just generate numbers for size 2 and 3 and rest will be NaN.

```
// Improved version
const createDigit = (size) => {
  if (size > 0) {
    const val1 = Math.pow(10, size) - 1
    const val2 = Math.pow(10, size - 1)
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (val1 - val2 + 1)) + val2
  }
  return 0
}

// Old buggy version
const createDigitBuggy = (size) => {
  var val1, val2
  size === 3 ? (val1 = 999, val2 = 100) : size === 2 ? (val1 = 99, val2 = 10) : 0
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (val1 - val2 + 1)) + val2
}


console.log(createDigitBuggy(1)) // prints NaN
console.log(createDigitBuggy(2)) // prints number
console.log(createDigitBuggy(3)) // prints number
console.log(createDigitBuggy(4)) // prints NaN


console.log(createDigit(1)) // prints number
console.log(createDigit(2)) // prints number
console.log(createDigit(3)) // prints number
console.log(createDigit(4)) // prints number
```

Comment: (Sorry, was just typing a comment)  This does not answer the question as asked.  Though I now see the OPs own "answer" and have voted to close his question as it's not clear if that's actually what he wants to ask.  Having said that your answer is OK but I'd remove the buggy implementation at least.

Comment: @AJP the buggy implementation is there for OP to compare, I am not saying to use that code.

Comment: ah I missed the "createDigitBuggy is yours" part.  Will remove downvote, though their answer is technically not buggy as a) it's not the actual question asked so by definition can't be buggy and b) if they just wanted 2 and 3 digit random numbers then it's also not buggy.  (Actually sorry SO doesn't let me change my vote now).